# Determine if a polynomial on a finite field is separable

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

If I want to determine if a given polynomial $P$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ is separable, what are the possibilities ? I mean :

- What is the general method ? I think it's to compute the GCD of $P$ and $P'$ with the Euclid algorithm, but I'm not sure.
- Is there any situations where tips can get the result faster ?

[Bonus] And for $k = \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Yes, just calculate $\gcd(P,P')$. As pointed out by DonAntonio, if $P(x)=Q(x^p)$ for some other polynomial $Q$, and you are working over a field of characteristic $p$, then separability is automatically violated, because $P'=0$. Then $\gcd(P,P')=P$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. And are there other tips over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Nothing springs to mind, I'm afraid. But calculating the GCD is quite efficient, so what kind of a polynomial $P$ you have in mind, if the Euclidean algorithm is not feasible?

Comment: I've in mind polynomials for which the Euclidean algorithm is feasible, but I ask myself if there are some tips for some special cases. Maybe there are not !

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment:

Any polynomial is separable over a field of characteristic zero, but be careful: this means that all the roots of the polynomial's *irreducible factors* are simple.

In case the characteristic is positive, say $\,p\,$ , we have that a polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ is **not** separable iff there exists another (separable) polynomial  $\,g(x)\,$  over the same field s.t. $\,f(x)=g(x^{p^n})\,\,,\,\,n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: I didn't know but there are two definitions of a separable polynomial : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial. I've not the same. For me, a polynomial P(X) over a given field K is separable if its roots are distinct in an algebraic closure of K.

Comment: Agree with Arnaud. This is wrong. $(x-1)^2$ is not separable over any field. You seem to be aiming at separability of irreducible polynomials, which comes in handy when discussing separability of algebraic field extensions.

Answer (score 1):

In any field, is $p(x)$ has repeated roots then it shares them with $p'(x)$, its (formal) derivative. So the GCD you mention helps weeding out multiple roots, but not to show if the polynomial is irreducible. If it is up to a quintic, checking that it has no linear or quadratic factors (by long division, and looking if some combination of coefficients give zero remainder) answers the question definitely, for higher degrees it gets messy...

Most computer algebra packages include efficient techniques to factor polynomials, perhaps take a trip through them. The (sadly unfinished) ["Computation in Finite Fields"](http://www.johnkerl.org/doc/ffcomp.pdf) by John Kerl might be of help.

Comment: Yes, it does not show if the polynomial is irreducible, but I just want to show that it is separable.

Comment: @Arnaud, proving one is the same as proving the other...

Comment: Come again? Separability does not imply irreducibility (and the reverse implication does not hold either, but that is less common, and does require infinite fields of positive characteristic).